# "Double" nested If statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, excel-formula

In [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubkrihmeej3h6ce/Example.xlsx) example I've manage to make the nested IF formulas remove < and >, convert . to , and multiply by 10.000 if there's a % sign. But text as >25.0 strings are added +1, but are not being multiplied by 10.000.

Can you please help me to understand what is wrong?

Formula were the error occurs (european comma and dot use):

```
=IF(
   ISNUMBER(SEARCH("<";Sheet!B8));SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet!B8;".";",");"<";"")/2;
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(">";Sheet!B8));SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet!B8;".";",");">";"")+1;
   IF(E$4="%";Sheet!B8*10000;Sheet!B8)))
```

Comment: Don't you need to substitute the comma before multiplying by 10000?

Comment: Examples (rather than just your descriptions) of your actual input, actual output, and desired output would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a couple of changes, try this out:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("<", Sheet!$B8)), SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet!$B8, "<", ""),".", ",")/2, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(">", Sheet!$B8)), SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet!$B8, ">", ""), ".", ",")+1)) * IF($E4 = "%", 10000, 1)
```

**EDIT:**

I hadn't looked at your provided code before hand, my bad. Try out the following code, if it isn't exactly what you're looking for let me know. My suggestion is to use this, and then go FORMAT CELLS > NUMBER > USE 1000 SEPERATOR.

```
=((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B5,"<",""),">","") + IFERROR((IF(SEARCH(">",B5)>0,1,0)),0)) / IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("<",B5)>0,2,1),1)) * IF($E$4="%",10000,1)
```

The reason is that by substituting the "." for the ",", excel treats it as text and you can't do basic algebra with text (i.e. 0,0001 or 25,0 are text, 0.000 1 and 25.0 are numbers). If you format to use the 1000 seperator, you can you the values as numbers and still have a properly formatted cell (eg. F6 = 181,000.00).

**EDIT2:**

```
=((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"<",""),">",""), ".", ",") + IFERROR((IF(SEARCH(">",B2)>0,1,0)),0)) / IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("<",B2)>0,2,1),1)) * IF($E$1="%",10000,1)
```

Comment: This seems to handle >25.0 correct, but turns everything else into zero?

Comment: A quick question. In the european version, the , and . are switched, so the "," should not make it text. But ok, I could omit that part and manually change the whole spreadsheet with a replace "." with ",". The function still doesn't work!? Thanks for the effort :-)

Comment: The function still doesn't work? Hmm, odd. I used it on your example spreadsheet and it gave the desired results. What error are you getting this time?

Comment: Well, it calculates >25 to 260.000 correct, but everything else turns zero with both versions!?

Comment: That's very odd. Using the same spreadsheet as you've provided, I get the desired output. I'm assuming then it has to be a difference with the excel version itself? Try the following, I'll add it in another EDIT as well. This gives me all #VALUE! errors but it might work in yours. `=((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"<",""),">",""), ".", ",") + IFERROR((IF(SEARCH(">",B2)>0,1,0)),0)) / IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("<",B2)>0,2,1),1)) * IF($E$1="%",10000,1)`

Comment: excellent! Wonder what I did wrong when i manually used 'replaced' for the "." and ",", because that seems to be the only change to your formula?! Thanks a million :-)